# Wordpress Installation - Change URL

Tags: apache2, wordpress

This question is in regards to changing my Wordpress URL.
So to begin, I've followed the Install and configure Wordpress guide posted on Ubuntu. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview

I've followed the steps with no issues, my Wordpress site is up and running.
The question is... how do I change my url from http://localhost/blog to an a http://example.com/?
In this tutorial, it makes you create an Apache site for WordPress. This is under /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf
In this wordpress.conf, you have an Alias followed by directory. I'll give an example...
Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress..

If I change the website URL's in the WordPress site in the General settings, what else do I need to change to reflect the changes?

I broke it by changing the Alias to a different name '/blog/ ---> '/newblog/'

Do I need to change the wordpress.conf file first before changing the URLs?

Answer (score 0):

### If you follow the Ubuntu Install & Configure WordPress guide, this solution will help you in updating the domain name of the site.

UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = 'http://new-domain-name.com'
WHERE option_name = 'home';

UPDATE wp_options
SET option_value = 'http://new-domain-name.com'
WHERE option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'http://old-domain-name.com','http://new-domain-name.com');

UPDATE wp_posts

### SET guid = REPLACE(guid,'http://old-domain-name.com','http://new-domain-name.com');

REFERENCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697144/change-site-url-and-wordpress-url-in-localhost

Comment: More information needed.  Presumably you're trying to get people to change some settings in a MySQL (or other database) but you don't make that clear.